# Select data from Multiple table and show merged data into view mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have two tables like

```
 USER_LOGIN

    USER_ID USER_NAME        PASSWORD
--------------------------------------------
       1    User 1          some data
       2    User2           somedata
       3    User3           Some Data
```

And

```
USER_DETAIL 
ID  USER_ID  NAME   ADDRESS
-------------------------------
 1     2    Name 2  Address
 2     3    Name    Three
```

Now how can select data from this two table by user id and show merged data into view??

Comment: Have you got any code at all?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do your join operation in SQL Server as a function
2. Bring the result of the function from database to application using LINQ
3. Apply your result to the grid datasource

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can make it through join concept in SQL server

```
select * from USER_LOGIN A join USER_DETAIL B on A.USER_ID=B.USER_ID
```

Now you'll get the all data from joining two tables and can pass to a datatable or dataset anything, then you can pass it to controller and to view. Still you can choose you join style it may be "leftjoin","rightjoin" like this.
Please refer these links for clear explanation

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm

Hope it helps!!!